# summarise with custom function for every combination of rows

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a longitudinal data set with repeated observations for each person:

```
df <- data.frame(person= c(rep(1,5), rep(2,10)),
                       x= c(0,rnorm(14)),
                       y= c(0,rnorm(14)))
```

I have a custom function that takes two `x` and `y` values as input and computes a value, like this:

```
myfunc <- function(x1, y1, x2, y2)
  return(x1+y1+x2+y2)
```

I now want to find the maximum value (or any other statistic) of all row combinations one person has.

Imagine `x` and `y` are geographic locations this person visited, `myfunc` calculates the distance between two x/y coordinates. I want to find the maximum distance between any of those points.

As you can see my data may have zeros where I do not know the values `x` and `y`, these rows should be skipped.

This should be in a summarise because my real data has many more variables and I use summarise for these as well.

So the first part should be:

```
result <- df %>% group_by(person) %>%
                     summarise(maxd = #maximum distance,
                               mind = #minimum distance,
                                ......)
```

My first thought would be to do this somehow with `expand.grid` to get all possible row combinations:

```
row.combis <- expand.grid(i=1:6, j=1:6) # all row combinations
row.combis <- row.combis[row.combis$j < row.combis$i, ] # skip duplicates
```

and then loop `myfunc` over the `row.combis` somehow.

But there must be a smarter way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say if you want to calculate the normal cartesian distance, you can use `dist()` function. Here is a `data.table` way to obtain the summary:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(maxd = max(dist(data.table(x, y))), 
              mind = min(dist(data.table(x, y)))), .(person)]

   person     maxd      mind
1:      1 3.264005 0.4734630
2:      2 2.514413 0.4359193
```

A corresponding `dplyr` method will be like:

```
df %>% group_by(person) %>% summarise(maxd = max(dist(data.frame(x, y))), 
                                      mind = min(dist(data.frame(x, y))))
Source: local data table [2 x 3]

  person     maxd      mind
   (dbl)    (dbl)     (dbl)
1      1 3.264005 0.4734630
2      2 2.514413 0.4359193
```

Comment: thanks, I didn't know about the built-in dist function. This is exactly what I want, but how are the zeros handled here?

Comment: If you are referring to the first row of your data frame where both `x` and `y` are zeros, it is just a normal point and it will be treated the same as other points in the `dist()` function.

Comment: ok, but the zeros are just placeholders and basically mean `NA`. I do not want to get wrong max and min distances based on them

Comment: You can use `df <- na.omit(df)` to exclude records that contain `NA`.

Comment: how can I do this in the summarise statement? Is something like this possible `summarise(maxd = filter(x !=0 & y !=0) %>% max(dist(data.frame(x, y))) )`

Comment: You can do it in the pipeline before the `summarise`, i.e., `df %>% group_by(person) %>% filter(x != 0 & y != 0) %>% summarise( ...`.

Comment: but my real data set has additional columns and no missings for observations where I don't know x and y. In my summarise statement I also have `summarise(maxd=..., mind=..., v4.mean = mean(v4))` assuming I have an additional column `v4`

Comment: One way to workaround is summarize other columns first, attach the result to original data frame and group_by these columns. So for example, if you want the mean of v4 also, you can do `df %>% group_by(person) %>% mutate(v4.mean = mean(v4)) %>% group_by(person, v4.mean) %>% filter(x != 0 & y != 0) %>% summarise( ... `.

Answer (score 0):

What about assigning the missing values to 'NA' instead of '0'. This would give you the option to perform simple tests like:

```
is.na(test_row[i])
```

or its compliment

```
is.finite(test_row[i])
```

Also this gives you access to handling these on the fly in your summarise() call. Most functions like mean(), max(), etc take an optional argument 'na.rm = logical'. The defualts are almost always FALSE, but switching this to "TRUE" can be very useful especially for numeric calculations.

Comment: yes, recoding the zeros to NA is possible, but I do not exactly see an answer in your posting